# What is the minimum processor frequency to bit bang CAN FD protocol

Tags: can-bus

I am working on a report on bit banging for various communication protocols.
I need information on hardware requirement to implement a particular protocol, mainly the minimum processor frequency requirement to run the code of bit banging for CAN FD ,MLVDS.
It will be better if get to know a more generic frequency requirement for running the code of bit banging for most of the communication  protocols.

If anyone has worked on it ,plz help me out .Any suggestions on sources where i can get this will be also helpful.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Do you have any idea how complex it would be to bit bang a CAN controller? I doubt you'll find anyone who has done that. Maybe you could find some skunky discarded project from the early 90s somewhere...

Comment: This (nearly 10 year old!) answer here goes into some depth on the complications of implementing CAN in software: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18134/20408 - and CAN FD has higher bit rates, so the timing is even more challenging.